# React Native calculating the distance between two coordinates using GeoLib

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-android

I have two issues. One is I can see the  Longitude and Latitude of my current location if I start the application using command react native run-android. If I reload the screen, I get a timeout error saying "Location Request timed out" and I don't see Longitude and Latitude. Below is the image

[image]

Another issue I am having is when I tried to calculate the  distance between two coordinates of Longitude and Latitude then I get  path error. Below is my code and the screen shot of the error:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Linking } from 'react-native';
import geolib from "geolib";

class GeolocationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }

  render() {

    let geolib = require('geo-lib');


    let result =geolib.Distance({
     p1: { lat: this.state.latitude, lon: this.state.longitude },
     p2: { lat: 33.613355, lon: -117.373261 }
 });


    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        <Text>Distance between two points:result </Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}


      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GeolocationExample;
```

[image]

I am not sure why this error is coming up.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this working updated code!

```
import {getDistance} from 'geolib';
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";

export default class Locations extends Component
{
    state = {  
        destinationLat: 31.6200,
        destinationLong: 74.8765,
        distance:null,
        startLat:52.528308,
        startLong:1.3817765
    };
    async componentDidMount(){
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
        });
        this.setState({
            startLat: location.coords.latitude,
            startLong: location.coords.longitude,
          });
        var dis = getDistance(
            {latitude: location.coords.latitude, longitude: location.coords.longitude},
            {latitude: this.state.destinationLat, longitude: this.state.destinationLong},
          );
          this.setState({
            distance: dis/1000,
          });
    };
    render(){
        return(
            <Text>{this.state.distance} KMs</Text>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The location timeout error is notorious for certain Android APIs. [This package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service) is meant to address this problem.

For your path problem, you're importing from 'geolib' with no dash at the top, but then are requiring 'geo-lib' *with* a dash within your render method. I would check to make sure which one you have installed and remove references to the other.